# undefined method `id' from self.id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a inbox messaging system from scratch and when I add self.id to the condition in the model I get a undefined method `id' error on all pages with a title of NoMethodError in MessagesController. I have tried a few workarounds though I can't get a grip on it.

messages_controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_user

  def index
    if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
      @messages = @user.sent_messages
    elsif params[:mailbox] == "inbox"
      @messages = @user.received_messages
    #elsif params[:mailbox] == "archieved"
     # @messages = @user.archived_messages
    end
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
    if params[:reply_to]
      @reply_to = User.find_by_user_id(params[:reply_to])
      unless @reply_to.nil?
        @message.recepient_id = @reply_to.user_id
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.sender_id = params[:user_id]
    if @message.save
      flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent"
      redirect_to user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox=>:inbox)
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @message = Message.readingmessage(params[:id],@user_id)
  end

  def delete_multiple
      if params[:delete]
        params[:delete].each { |id|
          @message = Message.find(id)
          @message.mark_message_deleted(@message.id,@user_id) unless @message.nil?
        }
        flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
      end
      redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = current_user
    end
end
```

user.rb:

```
:conditions => ["messages.recipient_deleted = ? AND messages.recipient_id = ?",false,self.id]
..
 ..

 def unread_messages?
   unread_message_count > 0 ? true : false
 end

 # Returns the number of unread messages for this user
 def unread_message_count
   eval 'messages.count(:conditions => ["recepient_id = ? AND read_at IS NULL", self.user_id])'
 end
```

Comment: This is because it is MessagesController's object not Message. self represent's the current object.

Comment: I'm not quite following. The self.id was define in the model, not controller.

Comment: simple: you imply self returns a User object and call user_id on it. however you made a mistake and self you can always use binding.pry and  print self to see what it is ;)